# Fresh 21.10 install can't play .mp4 files - what to do?

Tags: 21.10, codecs

I'm a little surprised that my fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10 can't play .mp4 files. This seems like a rather basic ability. Anyway, after getting very unhelpful errors in VLC, I installed the default GNOME player, totem, which gave me a more helpful error message: The necessary MPEG-4 AAV codec(s) is missing. But I fail to find any helpful info on where to get this. Not even here on askubuntu. What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When installing Ubuntu, users have the possibility of installing additional third-party drivers, codecs, firmware and other extras:

[image: Image of a previous Ubuntu release; should be the same for Ubuntu 21.10 or not fundamentally different]

Codecs can be installed *a posteriori* if this option isn't selected during the Ubuntu installation.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Thank you - this is it. I may have overlooked it because "additional media formats" is bundled with graphics and wi-fi hardware here.

Comment: Indeed. The only thing in common is that *some* may be proprietary so the reasoning was let's group them all together in this category and let users decide if they want the "package" or not.

Comment: Ah, well that makes sense.